# Spring, How to use repository polymorphism to return all data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I want to be able to create repository based on interface type. I did a little research and I got it work with this code:

```
interface Animal { }
@Document
class Dog extends Animal { }
@Document
class Cat extends Animal { }

interface AnimalRepository<A extends Animal> extends ReactiveCrudRepository<A, String>

interface DogRepository extends AnimalRepository<Dog>

interface CatRepository extends AnimalRepository<Cat>
```

No errors were thrown, everything work just fine, but I want to be able to do this.

```
class Test {

  @Autowired
  private AnimalRepository<Animal> animalRepository;

  public static void main() {
    // I want it to return both dog and cat from repository
    List<Animal> animals = animalRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

I want **AnimalRepository** to return all of animals in the database (dog, cat, etc..) when using **findAll** method. Is it possible to do so? I did try using the above code. it returns an empty list, but if I change generic type to **Dog or Cat** it will return a list of dog/cat respectively.

Comment: How are the entities defined? Is `Animal` an `@MappedSuperclass` or an `@Entity` itself? If the latter is the case, then the discriminator column and values should allow you to define a `ReactiveCrudRepository<Animal, String>`

Comment: I'm using mongodb. So it is @Document.

Comment: But the object hierarchy is not known to mongodb, right? A quick searched resulted in https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/, did you try that?

Comment: @RobSpoor Oh wait, your solution is actually working. Instead of using generic type, I use ReactiveCrudRepository<Animal, String> and it be able to find all Dog and Cat in the database. It returns abstract instance of animal which I have to cast it to concrete type (Dog, Cat), but it's fine I think?

Comment: you'll have no other choice if you have a `List<Animal>`. It doesn't matter where that comes from.